# Can we define a native query inside a Model in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have following model defined;

```
class Alarm extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'vwAlarm';
    protected $primaryKey = 'AlarmId';
    public $timestamps  = false ;


    public function scopeActiveAlarms($query)
    {
        return $query->whereDate('AlarmClearedUTCDateTime', '=', '9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999'); 
    }

    public function alarmTypeDesc()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(AlarmType::class, 'AlertTypeId', 'AlertTypeId');
    }

    public function Site()
    {
        $rec = \DB::table('vwAlarm')
            ->join('vwYfUserToSiteMappings as vw1', 'vwAlarm.SiteCode', '=', 'vw1.SiteCode')
            ->join('vwYfUserToSiteMappings as vw2','vwAlarm.CompanyId', '=', 'vw2.CompanyId')
            ->first();

        return $rec;
}
...

}
```

Im calling this model in my Controller like;

```
 $alarm = Alarm::findOrFail($id);
```

Here I see an issue, that `Site() method` in the Alarm model gives non relevant DB row.(I expect correct result for the `Id`($id) I passed)

What I'm doing wrong here? Is this right approach?

Comment: Your approach seems fine. What is your schema, with sample data?

Comment: @bishop i have tables already in my DB. (vwYfUserToSiteMappings and vwAlarm are two tables). Then the way I used join is wrong? I expect single row as output at $rec.

Comment: It's impossible to say if your SQL statement is correct, or not, without seeing your actual schema and corresponding sample data.

Comment: *non relevant DB*, without schema, example data, and expected input, that'd be difficult to figure things out.. also, i can't see anything that filters the raw query based on current model instance.. did you perhaps miss a `where` out there?

Comment: @BagusTesa Exactly, Thats what my question. When I use findOrFail($id) method, will that be applied to my Join?

Comment: not yet, basically, when you `findOrFail($id)` it only says that you will retrieve an item with given `$id`. It does not do 'magic' changing the raw query you have defined... it only do 'magic' for a proper eloquent relations.. you will need to define where and how this `$id` should be used in the raw query.. manually.. **ps** you could always call the `$id` in your `Site` method.

Comment: @BagusTesa thank you for clear answer

Comment: glad can be of help, happy coding!

Comment: @BagusTesa Forgot to ask; How Can I access that $id variable in my Site() method? Sample code would be helpful :)

Comment: Hi @Ratha, have you tried `$this->AlarmId` ? assuming the id column for the model is `AlarmId`.